# Weighting Labels in LightGBM Classifier in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, lightgbm, imbalanced-data

**Background**:

I am working with a LightGBM classifier in R. The data comprises four labels, which are imbalanced. Two of these labels seem to add noise to the data.

**Objective**:

I want to assign a weight to each label to handle the imbalance and noise.

**Questions**:

How do I appropriately assign these weights?

Should weights be applied only to the training set, or do they also need to be applied to the test set?
Here's a potential approach I'm considering:

```
dtrain = lgb.Dataset(data = train_x, label = train_y, weights = label_weights[trainIndex])
dtest = lgb.Dataset(data = test_x, label = test_y, weights = label_weights[-trainIndex])
```

For this approach:
Should `label_weights` be a vector of the same length as `trainIndex`?
Or should it be a vector of only 4 values, representing one weight for each label?